# How to delete Scaffolded Identity Area?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview Version 16.7.0 Preview 6.0 .I can add Identity scaffolded items,

[image]

but I cannot delete these folders and files. How to delete Scaffolded Identity Area items?

dialog box:

> 'Areas' and all its contents will be delete permanently

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your user account has access to the folder. Additionally, if IISExpress is running in your notification bar, you may need to stop the site as well.

Comment: **if IISExpress is running in your notification bar, you may need to stop the site as well.** is the key. Thank you!